# C# delete a folder and all files and folders within that folder

Tags: c#, directory

I'm trying to delete a folder and all files and folders within that folder, I'm using the code below and I get the error `Folder is not empty`, any suggestions on what I can do?

```
try
{
  var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@FolderPath);
  dir.Attributes = dir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
  dir.Delete();
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 221, accepted):

```
dir.Delete(true); // true => recursive delete
```

Answer (score 169):

Read the Manual:

[Directory.Delete Method (String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-delete(system-string-system-boolean))

```
Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
```

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(path,true)
```

This will recursively delete all files and folders underneath "path" assuming you have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 14):

For those of you running into the DirectoryNotFoundException, add this check:

```
if (Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) method has a recursive boolean parameter, it should do what you need

Answer (score 5):

Err, what about just calling `Directory.Delete(path, true);` ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
dir.Delete(true);
```

for recursively deleting the contents of that folder too. See MSDN [DirectoryInfo.Delete() overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c66e2tts.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
namespace EraseJunkFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo yourRootDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\somedirectory\");
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in yourRootDir.GetDirectories())
                    DeleteDirectory(dir.FullName, true);
        }
        public static void DeleteDirectory(string directoryName, bool checkDirectiryExist)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(directoryName))
                Directory.Delete(directoryName, true);
            else if (checkDirectiryExist)
                throw new SystemException("Directory you want to delete is not exist");
        }
    }
}
```