# Deleting Folder which Contains Many Sub Folder and Sub Folder Contains Many More

Tags: c#

I want to delete a folder (containing files and sub folder) and It's Sub Folder  containing many files and many Sub Folder and So on.. I Googled it but can't get success. Here is my Code.

```
private void TemporaryFiles_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool b = IsAdministrator();
            if (b != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Should Login as Admininstartor to run this Software at it's fullest.");
            }
            string TargetFolder = @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp";
            DeleteFolderAndFile(new DirectoryInfo(TargetFolder));
    }

static public void DeleteFolderFile(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        { 
            try
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //Do Nothing
                    }
                }
                foreach (DirectoryInfo Folder in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Folder.Delete(true);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //Do Nothing
                    }
                }
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DeleteFolderAndFile(subfolder);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //Do Nothing
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            { 
                //Do Nothing
            }

        }
```

Problem Is only Main Folder are left undeleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# delete a folder and all files and folders within that folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222718/c-sharp-delete-a-folder-and-all-files-and-folders-within-that-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the DirectoryInfo delete method with the Boolean argument of true to recursively delete. Call this once on the parent/target folder.

```
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(TargetFolder);

dir.Delete(true);
```

Comment: Already Used True while deleting folder but only main folder left undeleted.

Comment: Your code example does not appear to call delete on your parent folder. You should simply be able to call it once and the parent folder and all files/subfolders will be deleted (with appropriate permissions)

Comment: That's What I am asking. What to do to delete parent Folder.

Comment: I have updated to answer to be more specific. Call the delete method on the parent folder just as you do for subfolders in you method loops. Your method will be unnecessary.

Comment: Hildende has also provided the correct answer in the comment to your question. I lack rep to comment there, but have upvoted @hildende