# C# file delete and take long time to release process

Tags: c#

Delete file using C# from directory is holding the process for long time. How to kill process once the file is deleted.

Tried with 2 options of deleting the file,

Option 1:

```
path = @"C:\temp\a.xml";
File.Delete(path);
```

Option 2:

```
path = @"C:\temp\";
DirectoryInfo CVfiles = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (FileInfo CVfile in CVfiles.GetFiles())
{
     CVfile.Delete();
}
```

**Update**
*(from clarification in comments)*

```
 path = @"C:\temp\a.xml"; 
 DirectoryInfo CVfiles = new DirectoryInfo(path); 
 foreach (FileInfo CVfile in CVfiles.GetFiles()) 
 {
   CVfile.Delete(); 
 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);

Comment: Not to delete directory, Only selected file need to delete.

Comment: that's not what example 2 shows!

Comment: Oh sorry,

`path = @"C:\temp\a.xml";

DirectoryInfo CVfiles = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo CVfile in CVfiles.GetFiles())

{

     CVfile.Delete();

}   `

Answer (score 1):

You could try

[C# delete a folder and all files and folders within that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222718/c-sharp-delete-a-folder-and-all-files-and-folders-within-that-folder)

Ultimately the deletion will take as much as deletions needs.

> How to kill process once the file is deleted.

You can just exit the program.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But in my case, i can't close Application or program.

Once one function is tested, created file will be deleted. Then try for next function creating file with same name. Then it throws me IOException error "Program is using by another process"